# How to insert two separate bibliographies (without citing them in the body text) under two separate headers in R Markdown?

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, bibliography, csl

Consider the following R Markdown code:

```
---
title: 'John Doe'
output: pdf_document
bibliography: [bib1.bib, bib2.bib]
nocite: '@*'
csl: vancouver.csl
---

# Peer-reviewed publications

# Other publications
```

bib1.bib code:

```
@article{article1,
Author = {Doe, John},
Title = {{Article 1 name}},
Journal = {{Journal 1 name}},
Year = {{2021}},
Volume = {{1}},
Pages = {{1-2}},
}

@article{article2,
Author = {Doe, John},
Title = {{Article 2 name}},
Journal = {{Journal 2 name}},
Year = {{2020}},
Volume = {{1}},
Pages = {{1-2}},
}
```

bib2.bib code:

```
@article{article3,
Author = {Doe, John},
Title = {{Article 3 name}},
Journal = {{Journal 3 name}},
Year = {{2021}},
Volume = {{1}},
Pages = {{1-2}},
}
```

The knit output:

[image]

However, I'm rather looking after the following output:

[image]

Please note that I **don't** want in-text citations but rather the whole bibliographies listed, which is why I approached the problem by adding the "nocite: '@*'" to the code, but I couldn't get the result I'm after.

By the way, I used the csl style vancouver.csl (please see: https://www.zotero.org/styles?q=vancouver) here.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use biblatex to split the bibliographies:

```
---
title: 'John Doe'
output: 
  pdf_document:
    keep_tex: true
csl: vancouver.csl
header-includes:
  - \include{preamble.tex}
---
```

with `preamble.tex`:

```
\usepackage[style=vancouver]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bib1.bib}
\addbibresource{bib2.bib}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map[overwrite]{
      \perdatasource{bib1.bib}
      \step[fieldset=keywords, fieldvalue={,peer}, append]
    }
  }
}

\AtEndDocument{\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[keyword={peer},title={Peer-reviewed publications}]
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumber}{%
  \ifinteger{#1}
    {\number\numexpr#1-2\relax}
    {#1}}
\printbibliography[notkeyword={peer},title={Other publications}]}
```

And then compile the resulting `filename.tex` file with

```
pdflatex filename
biber filename
pdflatex filename
```

[image]

Comment: Very interesting approach. I installed biblatex-biber with MacPorts and your code is working beautifully. However, one issue: with your approach, under "Other publications" the list starts at number 3. although the number should be 1. (as it's a new list altogether).

Comment: @jaggedjava Please see my edited answer (replace the "2" in line 18 with whatever the last number in the first bibliography was)

Comment: I confirm that your code works perfectly!  I have two questions: 1) How do you feel about changing the line 18 to:  {\number\numexpr#1-#1+1\relax}  That could free the end user from any additional input to the code.  2) I also contemplated the incorporation of pdflatex-biber-pdflatex commands as bash commands to the R code, that would automate the process even further, but I'm not sure what would be the savviest way to do it. Now I'm running that chunk from a separate .Rmd-file, which works but is surely not the most effective/compact solution.

Comment: @jaggedjava Sure you can use `\number\numexpr#1-#1+1\relax` if you really like the number 1 :)

Comment: @jaggedjava If you want to automate the compilation, look into tools like latexmk or similar. They will automatically determine which steps are necessary